# Import Error after installing pyotherside

Tags: qt, python-3.x, pyotherside

I tried installing `pyotherside` from the ubuntu repos (packages `qml-module-io-thp-pyotherside` and `pyotherside`) as well as from the [git repo](https://github.com/thp/pyotherside).

But in when importing it in Python3 I keep getting `ImportError: No module named 'pyotherside'`.

Any knows why? What is the path where I should find pyotherside installed?

OS: Ubuntu 16.04.2

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`PyOtherSide` is a library that uses the python code from `QML` and not vice versa, in your project you must the qml file and the python file. To run the program you must execute the qml, for example:

```
{your directory}
├── imageprovider.py
└── imageprovider.qml
```

**imageprovider.py**

```
import pyotherside
import math

def render(image_id, requested_size):
    print('image_id: "{image_id}", size: {requested_size}'.format(**locals()))

    # width and height will be -1 if not set in QML
    if requested_size == (-1, -1):
        requested_size = (300, 300)

    width, height = requested_size

    # center for circle
    cx, cy = width/2, 10

    pixels = []
    for y in range(height):
        for x in range(width):
            pixels.extend(reversed([
                255, # alpha
                int(10 + 10 * ((x - y * 0.5) % 20)), # red
                20 + 10 * (y % 20), # green
                int(255 * abs(math.sin(0.3*math.sqrt((cx-x)**2 + (cy-y)**2)))) # blue
            ]))
    return bytearray(pixels), (width, height), pyotherside.format_argb32

pyotherside.set_image_provider(render)
```

**imageprovider.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import io.thp.pyotherside 1.5

Image {
    id: image
    width: 300
    height: 300

    Python {
        Component.onCompleted: {
            // Add the directory of this .qml file to the search path
            addImportPath(Qt.resolvedUrl('.'));

            importModule('imageprovider', function () {
                image.source = 'image://python/image-id-passed-from-qml';
            });
        }

        onError: console.log('Python error: ' + traceback)
    }
}
```

You open a terminal run:

```
qmlscene {your directory}/imageprovider.qml
```

Comment: Thank you, also for the interesting example. But why is the import not working without QML? Probably `pyotherside` would not know where to return its results to, but I would at least expect that Python3 would find the library (and maybe raise a error message pointing to this issue)?